# Complex valued trial solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[image]

For this problem, I've gotten the stage $$y'''' + 4y''' + 14y'' + 20y' + 25y = e^{(-1 + 2i)x} = e^{-x}( cos2x +i sin2x )$$

but am I not sure how to proceed from here. Is my trial solution $$e^{-x}(A_0 cos2x + A_1sin2x + iB_0cos2x + iB_1sin2x)$$ ?

Comment: Maybe you can do
$$
L = \frac {d^2}{dx^2} + 2 \frac d{dx} + 5
$$
and
$$
p = Ly
$$
then problem becomes
\begin{align}
Ly &= p \\
Lp &= e^{(-1 + 2i)x}
\end{align}

Comment: Note that $(-1+2i)x=-x+i·2x$. There is something missing in the exponential factor.

Comment: Updated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For any right side $g(x)=K·e^{λ x}$ the trial solution is $y(x)=A·e^{λ x}$. Provided that $λ$ is not a root of the characteristic equation. This is the best approach even when $λ$ is complex

In general, for a single exponential with a polynomial factor $g(x)=q(x)·e^{λ x}$ the trial solution is $y(x)=x^m·p(x)·e^{λ x}$ where the unknowns are the coefficients of $p(x)$ and $m$ is the multiplicity of $λ$ as root of the characteristic polynomial.

If the left side is completely real and the right is $K·e^{γ x}\cos(ω x)=K·Re(e^{(γ+i ω) x})$, with $k$, $γ$,$ω$ all real, then the most simple trial solution is $y(x)=Re(A·e^{(γ+i ω)})$ where now $A$ might be complex resulting in $\sin(ω x)$ as part of the solution.